# Replacing indices in a list without repeat index positions

Tags: python, list, indexing

So I have a list of 10 0's.

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].
```

I have to insert 4 random 1's into the list.

```
[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0].
```

How do I insert the 1's with no repeat indices.

```
def init_positions(n_cells, n_veh):
    lst = [0] * n_cells
    for i in range(n_veh):
        newL = random.randint(0, n_cells)
        lst[newL] = 1
    return lst

position = init_positions(10,4)
print(position)
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @goks The issue is random.randint(0,n_cells) can return the same value twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `random.sample` on a `range` to select n *distinct* indices.

```
import random

lst = [0] * 10

def insert_ones(n, lst):
    for x in random.sample(range(len(lst)), n):
        lst[x] = 1

insert_ones(4, lst)  # [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Alternatively, you can initialize your list directly this way instead of mutating it.

```
import random

def init_positions(n_cells, n_veh):
    indices = set(random.sample(range(n_cells), n_veh))
    return [1 if x in indices else 0 for x in range(n_cells)]

init_positions(10, 4)  # [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: `random.shuffle([0]*6 + [1]*4)`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque That's actually pretty neat! You should post it as an answer!

Comment: You should add it to yours, as an alternative option

Comment: It should actually be `seq = [0]*6 + [1]*4 ;
    random.shuffle(seq) ;
    print(seq)` because random.shuffle returns None

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Yes, I just realized that. I will not add it because it is not shorter than the solution with sample and is slightly less efficient since shuffle is more expensive.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thank You!